# pentaho not start error jackrabbit

Tags: debian, pentaho

I have a server whit debian 8, bi-server version 5.x. 
from today biserver not starting whit `/dir/biserver-ce/start-pentaho.sh`.
In `/biserver-ce/tomcat/logs/pentaho.log` I have this error but I can't resolve the error.
There is part of the log:

```
odooadmin@srv0015:/opt/biserver-ce/tomcat/logs$ cat pentaho.log
2017-05-02 10:58:30,252 ERROR
[org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl] Failed to initialize
workspace 'default' javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Unable to
initialize query handler:
org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex@7ac41a30  at
org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfigurationParser$1.getQueryHandler(RepositoryConfigurationParser.java:658)
  at
org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfig.getQueryHandler(RepositoryConfig.java:1037)
... Caused by: java.io.EOFException   at
java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)     at
org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.IndexInfos.read(IndexInfos.java:303)
  at
org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.IndexInfos.<init>(IndexInfos.java:107)
  at
org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.MultiIndex.<init>(MultiIndex.java:253)
  at
org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex.doInit(SearchIndex.java:555)
  at
org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.AbstractQueryHandler.init(AbstractQueryHandler.java:78)
  at
org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfigurationParser$1.getQueryHandler(RepositoryConfigurationParser.java:655)
  ... 220 more

2017-05-02 10:58:30,263 ERROR
[org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl] Unable to start
repository, forcing shutdown... 2017-05-02 10:58:30,543 ERROR
[org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl] failed to start
Repository: Unable to initialize query handler:
org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex@7ac41a30
javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Unable to initialize query handler:
org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex@7ac41a30  at
org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfigurationParser$1.getQueryHandler(RepositoryConfigurationParser.java:658)
...

Caused by: java.io.EOFException   at
java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)     at
org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.IndexInfos.read(IndexInfos.java:303)
  at
org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.IndexInfos.<init>(IndexInfos.java:107)
  at
org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.MultiIndex.<init>(MultiIndex.java:253)
  at
org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex.doInit(SearchIndex.java:555)
  at
org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.AbstractQueryHandler.init(AbstractQueryHandler.java:78)
  at
org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfigurationParser$1.getQueryHandler(RepositoryConfigurationParser.java:655)
  ... 220 more 2017-05-02 10:58:30,549 ERROR
[org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization
failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'filterChainProxy' defined in file
[/opt/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-spring-security.xml]:
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'basicProcessingFilter' defined in file
[/opt/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-spring-security.xml]:
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authenticationManager' while setting
bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'authenticationManager' defined in file
[/opt/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-spring-security.xml]:
Cannot create inner bean 'pen:bean#74e48049' of type
[org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.objfac.spring.BeanBuilder]
while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception
is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'pen:bean#74e48049': FactoryBean threw
exception on object creation; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name
'org.springframework.security.providers.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#1'
defined in file
[/opt/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-spring-security-jackrabbit.xml]:
Cannot create inner bean 'pen:bean#2a743bcc' of type
[org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.objfac.spring.BeanBuilder]
while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'pen:bean#2a743bcc': FactoryBean threw
exception on object creation; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'cachingUserDetailsService' defined in file
[/opt/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/pentahoObjects.spring.xml]:
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'UserDetailsService' while setting
constructor argument; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'UserDetailsService': FactoryBean threw
exception on object creation; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'userDetailsService' defined in file
[/opt/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-spring-security-jackrabbit.xml]:
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userRoleDaoTxn' while setting bean
property 'userRoleDao'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'userRoleDaoTxn' defined in file
[/opt/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/repository.spring.xml]:
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userRoleDao' while setting bean
property 'target'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'userRoleDao' defined in file
[/opt/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/repository.spring.xml]:
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'adminJcrTemplate' while setting
constructor argument; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'adminJcrTemplate' defined in file
[/opt/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/repository.spring.xml]:
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jcrAdminSessionFactory' while
setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'jcrAdminSessionFactory' defined in file
[/opt/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/repository.spring.xml]:
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jcrRepository' while setting
constructor argument; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'jcrRepository' defined in file
[/opt/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/repository.spring.xml]:
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Unable to initialize query handler:
org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex@7ac41a30
```

Please help me..

Comment: Looks like it's trying to read a configuration of some sort and the file is corrupted or something. "org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfig.getQueryHandler(RepositoryConfig.java:1037) ... Caused by: java.io.EOFException at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392) at " which tells me The input stream opened by getQueryHandler in the RepositoryConfig class is running into an unexpected End of File

Comment: i have noted also this error:
SEVERE: The web application [/pentaho] appears to have started a thread named [HSQLDB Timer @7b3e64f3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak
and
SEVERE: The web application [/pentaho] registered the JDBC driver [org.h2.Driver] but failed to unregister it  when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered

Answer (score 0):

Try killing all java processes, you might have started multiple instances of Pentaho. If nothing else helps, try restarting server.

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply. the one process java is pentaho.
user 20056  8.8  1.1 5153708 374244

Comment: pts/0  Sl   09:07  /usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/biserver-ce/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/biserver-ce/tomcat/endorsed -classpath /opt/biserver-ce/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/biserver-ce/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/opt/biserver-ce/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/biserver-ce/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start